# Dual Boot Debian on Raid 0 in UEFI mode

Tags: debian, dual-boot, lvm, raid, fakeraid

My new notebook came from the factory with Windows 8 on two 128GB SSDs in RAID 0 mode. I wanted to dual boot it with a Linux distro, I settled on Debian, so I resized my `C:` drive as one normally would to free up some space for the Linux install. I installed from `debian-live-7.8.0-amd64-kde-desktop` which runs on Linux kernel `3.2.0-4`. I initially followed these [instructions on Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/SataRaid) for installing on SataRAID aka BIOS RAID.

I deviated from the instructions on the wiki in step 8, as the Debian rescue install console did not give me the option to mount and use `/dev/dm-?` as the root fs and I needed to set up Debian to boot in UEFI mode via Ubuntu Live anyway, primarily using instructions in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLlOd-a2wG0), which basically involve using Ubuntu to mount the Debian filesystem, mounting the EFI partition in the Debian file system, then bind mounting `/dev/`, `/dev/pts`, `/proc/`, and `/sys`, and finally `chroot` to the Debian directory to update the `sources.list` and updating all of Debian's packages.

Lastly, `apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi` followed by `install-grub /dev/mapper/isw_<somechars>_Volume1` to make sure to use the raid volume and not `/dev/sdx`.

So now I am able to boot into `Grub` but when I select Debian it fails to load, giving me 'Gave up waiting for root device' error, and claiming the 'isw_...' disk does not exist. Can anyone offer some guidance on how to troubleshoot further? I also was not clear about a line on the original page I linked that says, "install Debian as usual, until you get to the disk partitioner. You will see your fake RAID as one disk with a confusing long name. Use it as if it were a single disk and configure your partitions any way you want, including LVM and friends." What does it mean by "including LVM and friends? Did I need to explicitly make the drive an LVM drive when I performed the partitioning during the original install? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!